# Wiring for Recessed Lighting

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfdso.jpg

I am looking to rewire my office to install recessed lighting and want to make sure I got everything correct.  15A circuit.  Outlet 1 contains white and black from source, sends to outlet 2 then outlet 2 to switch.  Orange wire is shared between outlet 1 and switch.  All the blacks are hot and all whites are not hot.

First step is to replace outlet 1 with a new one to make both sides always hot.  Replace with new outlet keeping tab intact, completely remove orange wire.

Next step is to run white wire from outlet 2 into switch box.  In switch box using 14/2 NM-B, wire nut white to white, black to switch replacing orange, and ground wire mounted to back of box.

Next run 14/2 up the wall into ceiling.  Daisy chain into 6 recessed lights ending at the final 6th light.

After much research into this I believe I have it correct.  Any help or information with this is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you provide a wiring diagram, this would enable you to effectively communicate our wiring plan.   Hint: make it easy for others to help you

Answer (score 1):

You have a good, sound plan. It's good to see you didn't want to use
the orange wire for your white/neutral wire. What you can do is attach your new white wire to the orange and use the orange to pull the white wire from the outlet to the switch box.